# i need a simple javascript to add and multiply costs

Tags: php, javascript, html, scripting

can anyone give me a javascript that can do following. 
I have predefined price for a product (lets say A). the consumer can select the quantity (lets say B)for that product. and the total price(lets say C where C=A*B) shows up on the same page without him actually pressing any button.
If there are 5 different products he chose then at the bottom the total price ("C") for each product adds up automatically (lets say D)at the bottom. (i will use this total price ("D") by passing it into a header command of php on some other page).
 I know html and css and a little php but i have no idea of javascript. I am making this website for a book store . The owner is a real good friend and i want to make it the best i can. Thanks for your help 

for example
this is what i want to happen. i am selling 5 different books on the same page. you can select the books you want and the quantity of each book. ( for example 3 books of type 1 and 2 books of type 2). At the bottom of the page the calculation occurs automatically and the buyer can see the total amount he has to pay

Comment: Please provide more information. What HTML markup are you using? What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: this si what i want to happen. i am selling 5 different books on the same page.
you can select the books you want and the quantity of each book. ( for example 3 books of type 1 and 2 books of type 2). At the bottom of the page the calculation occurs automatically and the buyer can see the total amount he has to pay.

Comment: If you show us your HTML form, we can show you the script you will need to accompany it. You must make sure that it is validated server side else the user could (e.g using FireBug) submit the form showing $0.01 and get 99 copes of each book.

Comment: you'll certainly have to use parseInt() in javascript to make some arithmetics, when it will be the case, just be careful, parseInt takes a second arg which is the base -- 10 for you-- so you'll always have to write it like that foo=parseInt(bar,10);

Comment: i havent got it prepared right now and how can i show it in this question. I was looking and i found this site vegoncall.com

Comment: i want something like that except i want to sell books instead of vegetables and fruits.

Comment: See if you can tweak [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZaN5/) to fit your needs. If you like this approach you have to know it requires jQuery [Calculation plugin](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm). Though, for such a simple case as yours a plugin might be too much. Show the markup you like and someone will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_math.asp

And

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

The final one is more complex, and is for the dynamic post to the PHP file. Before asking for the code from someone else, try your hardest to see if you can learn to do it yourself... it'll count in the long run.

Comment: i never ask for codes but i thing is that i dont want to screw up someones business . I am not even doing it for money or anything. I asked coz i want his business to be set up fast.

Comment: Just have a quick read of those links danny, should help fine. It's not hard, if you know PHP you should be fine. Kbok... w3schools is fine for beginners, that link (w3fools.com) is a bit over the top to be fair, w3schools helped me learn.

Comment: @rickyduck: was also using w3schools to learn coding (at my beginner days )  and over the years i had to *unlearn* when things i learned from there were very mis-leading. also MDN Docs is a much better option. its a good practice to always search like "onchange mdn" to get accurate infos

Answer (score 1):

The only trick in JavaScript for adding or multiplying numbers is that, you should first get sure they are numerical values rather than strings. To do that, you can cast them to numbers via:

```
var value = $('#input').val();
if(Number(value))
{
   // Do your work here
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention or tag jQuery, so this may confuse them.

Comment: Yeah, I know, the only emphasis here is on casting the value to number :)